# Sitecore Web form for marketers: Change Name/ID of fields that is generated

Tags: input, field, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

Is it possible to actually change the WFFM generated `<input id=**"[ID]"** name=**"[name]"** />` for each field? 
Or is always have to be in that manner?

Note: This requires for it to not be exported to a ascx file and be modified.
I'm trying to store field data into Web Cache, and it's increasingly hard to target with such IDs/Name using `Request.Form[]`

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? There may be another approach that won't require you to change how WFFM generates the fields

Comment: Just curious on it's capabilities and customizations. I want to be able to manipulate the field ID to check if the input value is empty or populated on submission.

Comment: I've added an answer containing two possible ways you can manipulate a field, its I'd and value to validate and verify what the used has entered. Don't forget to vote / mark it as the answer to help others out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if the input value is empty or populated on submission you have two options available.

The first is achieved via the `Form Designer` in the Content Editor. For each field you can define if it is a required field, min/max length and apply regular expressions against the value (Sitecore comes with a few out-of-the-box). You can also fully control the validation text to help guide your users.

This image shows the validation section that is on the left of the `Form Designer`

[image]

This validation occurs in-line, before the Form is submitted, or on the submit click event.

You can even create your own `Field Validators` which you can also apply via the `Form Designer`. I've recently written another [answer on how to create Custom Field Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966736/sitecore-customvalidator-does-not-fire-on-wffm-custom-field) that can help you.

The other option is extend or create your own `Save Action`, in non-Sitecore speak the submit action that is triggered when the Form button is pressed.

At this point you have access to all `Fields` on the Form and perform any manipulation on the values entered by the user.

```cs
public class CustomFormSubmit : ISaveAction
{
    public void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
    {

        try
        {
            // Loop through each field in the form
            foreach (AdaptedControlResult field in fields)
            {
                // Properties so you could manipulate field Id and Value
                field.Id
                field.FieldName
                field.Value

                // logic to manipulate field
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex.Message + ":" + builder, ExceptionCategory.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

There is a little extra work in Sitecore you need to do to get your new `SaveAction` selectable for WFFM, but I've covered this in a blog about [Custom Save Actions](http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/02/18/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-send-email-with-attachment-save-action/), its pretty straight forward

I'm not certain how far you could go with manipulating FieldIds but this is a simple way of checking and playing with the field and its value.